# What do you call a looping progress bar?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, progress-bar

Ok I'm just at a loss for what the correct terminology is for this.  I'm looking for the correct name to call a progress bar that "loops".  Instead of the standard progress bar that fills up from left to right to 100%, this looks exactly like the progress bar but a small portion of the fill color constantly loops, never filling the whole progress bar to 100%, basically making it an eternal progress bar similar to a [Ajax loading image](http://www.ajaxload.info/).  Microsoft likes to use this progress bar in their dialogs now.

What do you call this thing so I can search for some controls, etc.?  Does .Net have a control for this?

Thanks

Comment: Annoying :P.  Progress bars shouldn't give me false hope, darnit!

Comment: So timely:  http://www.xkcd.com/612/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Windows the progress bars are said to be in Marquee mode I think.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760816%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: **Any Circular-and-Indeterminate progress is a Spinner** (or `ProgressSpinner`), but the OP targets dot-net (i.e. Microsoft) and "`bar`", hence most votes go here.

Answer (score 13):

[Indeterminate progress bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_bar)?

Java's [`JProgressBar`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) specifically refers to "Indeterminate mode"

Comment: You got the terminology correct so I upp'd your answer, but I like the answer smack0007 gave me because he points to a solution I can try right away in my IDE.  Both yours and his answers were a toss-up :)

Comment: Thanks Sentax. It's better that you chose smack0007's response. Using the terminology that is used by the platform is always preferable.

Answer (score 5):

In GTK, its a normal progress bar, just set it to "Pulse" mode.

Answer (score 3):

I've always known a busy indicator that doesn't indicate relative progress as a "spinner". It may be a bar in this case, but it's the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard it called the following:

- [Cylon progress bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylon_(1978)#Popular_culture) ([in Netscape](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/ben/archives/007299.html))
- Knight Rider progress bar
- [PATWOCEM](http://blogs.msdn.com/texblog/archive/2007/04/30/progress-bar-the-lie-we-all-accept.aspx)

Comment: LOL! - Yes.  "Knight Rider progress bar" is definitely my favourite way I've heard user's describing them.

Answer (score 0):

A google search for "loading gif" returns quite a few examples.  Loading icon works too.

http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&um=1&sa=1&q=loading+gif&btnG=Search+images&aq=f&oq=loading+gi

Comment: I provided a link in my question to a tool that allows you to create this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same boggle a while back while I was designing the pop up image gallery on ebuyer.com. I think a "pre-loader" or "loading animation" is probably the most accurate description.

A progress bar gives actual visual feedback on the amount of time you can expect to wait, whereas you are just looking to give the user some feeback that their action has been acknowledged and the response is pending.
I think windows describes the cursor as "wait". In Mac land we know it as the "beach ball".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what they're called, but they bug me.  They're a misapplication of a tool designed to do one thing - indicate how close a long-running task is to completion - to a different problem - reassure the user that a long-running task of indeterminate length is actually still running.

One of the things that is most infuriating to the user (and by "the user," I mean "me") is something you see Microsoft doing every so often:  a task is running, the progress bar is gradually filling, and then, when it gets to the end, it starts over again.  And you realize that you've been lied to:  the UI told you that the task was about to complete, but suddenly you can see that's not true, the program actually doesn't have any idea when the task's going to complete.

Comment: I feel your pain, I always hated seeing the progress bar for an installation go from 0% to 100% about 10 times during a simple installation, I figure they broke the progress status up into what stage the install is in, but it's very annoying that you can't trust that if the progress is on 80% that it's actually 80% complete.

Another one is the progress bar goes fast and smooth all the way to 99%, this can only mean the developers didn't calculate the install correctly.

Now, my purpose is for a WCF client that will make a call to the server, I have no way to know how long this op will be.

Comment: There are lots of times that you won't know how long a long-running task will take to complete.  When that happens, use something other than a progress bar to indicate that the application's still alive.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard it called a **Spinner**

Answer (score 0):

'Throbber' is also a term that's used widely.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Wi6C1xNhbg

This is using the﻿ progress bar in VB﻿ 2008. To reverse the animation just change a few properties of the progress bar: 'RightToLeft' to yes and 'RightToLeftLayout' to true. Then use a timer to flip the properties back each time.